# Store a variable and use it on the entire domain

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, variables

I'm making a new computer builds page. I can't go further because I have an issue. I have a table row like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Part</td>
    <td>Part name</td>
    <td>Part description</td>
    <td id="partPrice">Part price</td>
</tr>
```

The part's price goes into the cell *partPrice* but I will use the same part in other build and when the part's price changes I will have to change it manually in all pages using that part. So I want to store a part's price value somewhere and access it from all my wesite pages. HOW CAN I DO IT?

P.S. It doesn't matter what programming language I will have to use to do get this working

Comment: Well, yes. As you have already tagged the question MySQL, that's a decent place to start. You'll also need a server-side programming language of some sort; server-side Javascript will do, but anything like like PHP, Ruby, C# or whatever will too. Learn any of them and do it. This is too broad to answer in detail.

Comment: First of all, you need to determine what programming language you're going to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have tagged Mysql, why don't you make a constants table which will contains all the variables you need ?

You would make a call for the table/elements in the table to get the desired value(s), and it would still be easy to change them.

Comment: Ok. So how I will do that? I don't know much about mysql and databases. And I don't know what is a "constant table"...

Comment: A constant table is just a table with values that will be constant (unchanged).

What have you tried to do so far ?

Comment: I have tried to declare a variable in external .js file and use it in internal script in the page. But the <td> was blank.

Comment: Oh. Ok. It is working. I have forgotten to click a cell because I set to write a value to it onClick(). Solved!

Comment: Update your post with the codes you used, i will help you with your solution.